# Como navegar entre telas no React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Seguinte, tenho um arquivo de rotas, app.routes.js, nele criei um **MaterialBottomTabNavigator** e está funcionando perfeitamente. Mas estou com a seguinte duvida. Por exemplo, dentro da minha tela de "Acessos" eu quero que um botão leve para uma tela chamada "Formulário", mas não quero que essa rota esteja visível no BottomTab.

app.routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from '../pages/Home';
import Acessos from '../pages/Acessos/Index';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import CriarAcessoForm from '../pages/Acessos/form';

import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

export default function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBarActiveTintColor="red"
      activeColor="#50cfc9"
      barStyle={{backgroundColor: '#0c222b'}}
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
        tabBarActiveTintColor: 'red',
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen name="criarAcessoForm" component={CriarAcessoForm} />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({color, size, focused}) => {
            return (
              <MaterialIcon
                focused={focused}
                name="home"
                color={!focused ? '#234655' : '#50cfc9'}
                size={20}
              />
            );
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Acessos"
        component={Acessos}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({color, size, focused}) => {
            return (
              <MaterialIcon
                color={!focused ? '#234655' : '#50cfc9'}
                name="add-circle"
                size={20}
              />
            );
          },
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Eu achei algumas coisas dizendo para eu importar o **navigation** como *props* dentro do componente que quero fazer esse redirecionamento, que no caso seria o componente abaixo, porém quando chamo a função pra mudar de rota da o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

export default function CriarAcessos({navigation}: any) {
  return (
    <Container>
      <ButtonWrapper onPress={() => navigation.navigate('criarAcessoForm')}>
        <FormButtonText>Preencher formulário</FormButtonText>
        <MaterialIcon name="edit" size={20} color={'#fff'} />
      </ButtonWrapper>
      <ButtonWrapper title="PageCriars">
        <FormButtonText>Enviar Ficha</FormButtonText>
        <MaterialIcon name="file-upload" size={20} color={'#fff'} />
      </ButtonWrapper>
      <ButtonWrapper title="PageCriars">
        <FormButtonText>Download Template</FormButtonText>
        <MaterialIcon name="file-download" size={20} color={'#fff'} />
      </ButtonWrapper>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: Creio que o jeito mais fácil seja você criar um stack navigation e coloca-lo dentro do bottom tabs.